# Trigger a build in TeamCity whenever a tag is present in the commit

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I am using TeamCity 9.01 as my CI server. I am currently using a VCS trigger which will trigger for a regular expression. But this regular expression in the commit message is making the look of work flow in source tree a little too clumsy. So I decided to trigger a build whenever a tag is added. But I couldn't find any solution.Please help me out.

Comment: Could you please try to explain what you want to achieve rather what is your solution for that? It will be easier to find a solution I think.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using tags, I'd expect you also want to build with exactly tagged revision?
To do so you can configure your VCS root and VCS trigger to watch for tags, add `+:refs/tags/(*)` to VCS root branch settings in case of git.
With VCS trigger builds will run for newly detected and modified tags.